# Geany annonying line

Tags: 14.04, geany

I am using `Geany` for C programming. There is an annoying line where I am typing. An image can explain it better. I uninstalled and installed `Geany` with no luck.

How do I get rid of the line?

[image]

Geany version: *1.23.1*
OS: *Ubuntu 14.04.2 64 bit*

Comment: That "annoying line", btw, is a long line marker, there to guide you and keep you from writing long lines of code that cause horizontal scrolling when people like, oh, me, look at your code. :)

Comment: You code using that font?! o_O JK

Comment: Yeah i love it.It's `Purisa`.

Comment: @MarvinMicek I dig it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the preferences, then the Editor->Display Tab. Finally uncheck the long line marker **Enabled** checkbox:

[image]

Comment: @JacobVlijm: The first thing I do when reinstalling a system is changing this line from 72 to 80 :)